# OpenCart changes type attributes of inputfields

Tags: php, html, opencart, user-input, input-field

I'm facing a strange thing here. I'm working on an OpenCart, register form (`index.php?route=checkout/register`).
I have the form and 2 fields like this:

```
<span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_email; ?><br />
<input type="text" name="email" value="" class="large-field" /><br />
<br />
<span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_telephone; ?><br />
<input type="text" name="telephone" value="" class="large-field" />
```

Now: The browser interprets these 2 fields as:

```
<input type="email" name="email" value="" class="large-field">
```

and

```
<input type="tel" name="telephone" value="" class="large-field">
```

BUT if I change the email field attribute-order like so:

```
<input type="text" value="" class="large-field" name="email" />
```

then the fields are truly text types, they don't get transformed.
*Attention*: I only modify for the first one (email) and after that the email and the telephone are parsed correctly.

I am seeing this unexpected behavior on Firefox, Chrome and Opera,
however, if I copy the inputs in a plain html and view it, they are ok..

Any idea on what is happening, and of course why?

**EDIT:**
The full HTML that is sent to the browser (retrieved with [web-sniffer.net](http://web-sniffer.net)) is in this pastebin:  http://pastebin.com/bCXab6Kb

That means that the `<input type="text"` fields are already changed when php sends the HTML to the browser.
So, what (why/how) converts the `<input type="text">` to type `email`/`tel` (seemingly based on name attribute) and why does this fail when the input-field's attribute order is changed?

Comment: seriously use some \n ... i can't read anything in this mess. thank you

Comment: @dan: I edited it to tidy up the markup. Have a look now.

Comment: thanks for the edit, sorry I was in a hurry :P

Comment: it could be either two things changing it: JavaScript or the Browser that 'smartly' auto-detects it and thus transforms it accordingly, which I believe you're probably using Chrome?

Comment: I thought of js too, but it is not. It wouldn't make sense anyway, cause js would also find and change that input, it does not take care about the order of attributes. I think of browser too. BTW, yes it is Chrome. I don`t think this is ok, I mean the browser should definitely not transform our attributes, it can cause serious problems. Maybe it is just my oppinion...

Comment: The solution for me was simple, as I have offered a solution in the question itself, I wanted to share this experience with the others and also wanted to find a possible answer or explanation for this.

Comment: What happens if you add `autocomplete="off"` to the form-tag? It might help (for future reference) if you could add the Crome-version where this happens. (By the way, didn't Chrome recently switch from webkit to blink ?)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. There is no form, these are just inputs. The values of there are posted via ajax, but there is no actual form tag defined there.

Comment: did u try it on other browsers as well?

Comment: No problem, what if you'd wrap the fields in a form (with and without the `autocomplet="off"` attribute)? EDIT: same in FF as in chrome? And the plot thickens.. Maybe some script after all?

Comment: @GitaarLAB same with form too

Comment: Hmm, it's time to setup a quick jsfiddle without any opencart etc and check it again (if everything works normal, it must be something with opencart, thus script).

Comment: It may be something with opencart too, because if I copy the inputs in a plain html and view it they are ok.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't disable js's because the "form" is shown only after selecting the option to register, which is handled by javascript. This happens on the checkout page, you may select to login or register, I choose register and after that the template for registration containing the fields is populated into a div. Normal user registration works ok(not by checkout)

Comment: I updated your question based on the comments and progress we've made in the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCart up to current stable [version 1.5.6](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/v1.5.6/) (and [version 1.5.6.1](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/v1.5.6.1/) as it currently is,) does not use any HTML5 (input fields etc) by default (or in it's default theme).
This is in-line with: [When will opencart start to use html5?](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=57811&p=270011) (apr. '12): *"People are still complaining about IE6 support. When people stop whining about that, then we can start focusing on HTML5 transitioning"*.

For example, the file [checkout/register.tpl](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/v1.5.6/upload/catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/register.tpl) (from v 1.5.6) (that you modified) contains by default:

```
<span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_email; ?><br />
<input type="text" name="email" value="" class="large-field" />
<br />
<br />
<span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_telephone; ?><br />
<input type="text" name="telephone" value="" class="large-field" />
```

However, in the current [master-branch](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/) (dec. '13) I *am* seeing some *inconsistent* use of HTML5 input-fields in *some* pages (like: [`account/register.tpl`](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/catalog/view/theme/default/template/account/register.tpl) and [`account/edit.tpl`](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/catalog/view/theme/default/template/account/edit.tpl)):

```
<div class="form-group required">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-email"><?php echo $entry_email; ?></label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_email; ?>" id="input-email" class="form-control" />
    <?php if ($error_email) { ?>
    <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_email; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group required">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-telephone"><?php echo $entry_telephone; ?></label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="tel" name="telephone" value="<?php echo $telephone; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_telephone; ?>" id="input-telephone" class="form-control" />
    <?php if ($error_telephone) { ?>
    <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_telephone; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-fax"><?php echo $entry_fax; ?></label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" name="fax" value="<?php echo $fax; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_fax; ?>" id="input-fax" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

<sup>Note how the fax field has `type="text"` and the absence of tables (in favor of divs) and finally the different classnames.</sup>

---

That brings us to the most interesting part of your question: *what (why/how) converts the `<input type="text"` to type `email`/`tel` (seemingly based on name attribute) and why does this fail when the input-field's attribute order is changed?.*

As we can see in the HTML code sent by PHP to the browser (http://pastebin.com/bCXab6Kb), the input-field's type attributes are already changed. Thus it is not the browser or a piece of javascript that changes this.
So, assuming PHP doesn't change the code by itself, there must be something in the script(s) that PHP runs to change the code as stored in files on the harddisk before sending it to the browser: OpenCart and/or (one of) it's 'themes', 'modules', 'extensions' etc.
And since some kind of html-parser probably wouldn't mess up such a simple task, the most likely candidate is some kind of script that does a basic search and replace.

There happen to be 2 (highly related) scripts, common to OpenCart, that exactly fit this bill..

1. OpenCart's 'modification system'
   Should you have accidentally downloaded/installed the 'latest' (development) master-branch (or are a contributer), then you'll find some files like [system/engine/modification.php](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/system/engine/modification.php) (and some related files and database-table) that can search for and prepend/append/replace lines of code in php/tpl files (hard-coded limitation) according to rules specified in an xml file ([system/modification.xml](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/system/modification.xml)) *before the targeted php/tpl file is parsed* and *without modifying the original file(s)*.
   This rather self-explanatory xml-file basically contains 'operations' per file to modify on the fly, for example:

   ```
   <file name="system/engine/front.php">
     <operation>
       <search>
         <![CDATA[$action->getFile()]]>
       </search>
       <add position="replace">
         <![CDATA[$this->registry->get('modification')->getFile($action->getFile())]]>
       </add>
     </operation>
   </file>
   ```

   where `$action->getFile()` is replaced with `$this->registry->get('modification')->getFile($action->getFile())` *before* file `system/engine/front.php` is parsed!
2. "[vQmod™](http://code.google.com/p/vqmod/)" (aka Virtual Quick Mod)
   vQmod is a separately developed package and is basically a polished version of OpenCart's modification system (above), from which it [originated](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=40987). It is commonly used by 'add-ons' to modify production-releases of OpenCart and [installed](http://code.google.com/p/vqmod/wiki/Install_OpenCart) (as it is not included in OpenCart by default) in folder `vqmod` (located in the root of OpenCart). Inside this folder you'll find a folder `vqcache` that holds the cached modified files and a folder `xml` that holds the `xml search/replace files`.
   These xml files have a slightly different [syntax](http://code.google.com/p/vqmod/wiki/Examples) (most notably the `position` attribute) compared to OpenCart's modification system (above):

   ```
   <file name="catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/register.tpl">
     <operation>
       <search position="replace">
         <![CDATA[<input type="text" name="email" value="" class="large-field" />]]>
       </search>
       <add>
         <![CDATA[<input type="email" name="email" value="" class="large-field" />]]>
       </add>
     </operation>
     <operation>
       <search position="replace">
         <![CDATA[<input type="text" name="telephone" value="" class="large-field" />]]>
       </search>
       <add>
         <![CDATA[<input type="tel" name="telephone" value="" class="large-field" />]]>
       </add>
     </operation>
     <operation>
       <search position="replace">
         <![CDATA[<input type="text" name="fax" value="" class="large-field" />]]>
       </search>
       <add>
         <![CDATA[<input type="tel" name="fax" value="" class="large-field" />]]>
       </add>
     </operation>
   </file>
   ```

   <sup>Note: above example is from the 'embermonkey responsive theme' and is an excellent example of the behavior of what you are experiencing: it replaces the input attributes.</sup>

The purpose of these modification-scripts is to:

> avoid having to change core files. The concept is quite simple... Instead of making changes to the core files directly, the changes are created as xml search/replace script files. These script files are parsed during page load as each "source" core file is loaded with the "include" or "require" php functions. The source is then patched with the script file changes, and saved to a temp file. That temp file is then substituted for the original during execution. The original source file is never altered. This results in a "virtual" change to the core during execution without any actual modification to the core files.

This makes it possible to "virtually alter any php or tpl file in OpenCart (except the main index.php)" so that it will become easier and more reliable to update OpenCart's core files *and* add/remove templates etc.

---

Finally, the valid email address (letters@gmail.com) that fails to validate when the input's type is set to `email` instead of `text`...
This is a rather common problem with (broken/outdated/partially-installed) 'responsive'/'mobile' themes etc. (that usually also affects telephone fields) <sup>[1](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=109803), [2](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=108834)</sup>.
The problem is not that the browser rejects the valid email-addres (when the input field's type is set to `email` instead of `text`); instead, it's OpenCart's JSON validator that doesn't get input types `email` (and `tel`, etc) by default (when you or the theme left this unpatched):

```
$('#button-guest').live('click', function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: 'index.php?route=checkout/guest/validate',
      type: 'post',
      data: $('#payment-address input[type=\'text\'], #payment-address input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #payment-address input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #payment-address input[type=\'hidden\'], #payment-address select'),
      dataType: 'json',
```

Thus, obviously, the [solution](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=109803#p455634) is to add these input-types to the AJAX-call:

```
$('#button-guest').live('click', function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: 'index.php?route=checkout/guest/validate',
      type: 'post',
      data: $('#payment-address input[type=\'text\']
             , #payment-address input[type=\'email\']   // added
         //  , #payment-address input[type=\'tel\']     // added
             , #payment-address input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked
             , #payment-address input[type=\'radio\']:checked
             , #payment-address input[type=\'hidden\']
             , #payment-address select'
             ),
      dataType: 'json',
```

---

In conclusion, using what is explained above:

- Most probably you either installed some kind of 'Complete'/'Popular' re-distribution of OpenCart that included vQmod *or* you upgraded an existing OpenCart installation that included vQmod *or* you installed some kind of add-on that depends on vQmod and installed that by itself.
- To find and disable this mod you'd first search your OpenCart directory for a folder called 'vQmod'. If you can not find it, you do a text-search (starting in your OpenCart directory and including subdirectories) for strings containing `<input type="email"` (for example) and investigate results with file-type xml first.
- To use the mod without having validation (of email, telephone, fax, etc) fail, fix the JSON call (you could use vQmod should it be already installed and just add this as an operation for the affected files).
- Alternatively (as you have already noticed), have the mod crash by changing the attribute order (at the price of other mods for this page also failing as you noticed).
- If none of the above works in your case, I'd *highly recommend to re-install a clean version of OpenCart!*

PS: now you know of vQmod, you'd better use it (instead of modifying core-files) since "performance suprisingly does not appear to be a factor at all", giving you the benefit of a more reliable upgrade-path in the future!

Comment: I actually do use vqmod, but for now I did not even think it could be the "guilty one". I think you are absolutely right with that, I too use embermonkey vqmod xml file. Thanks for the explanation, and the digging, I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the behaviour You are describing is not coming from OpenCart at all - at least not from the default installation with the default theme.

You can turn off the JS and access this page directly: `http://your.ocinstall.com/index.php?route=account/register` - it will open the registration page.

Anyway, in default installation (and default theme) there is this HTML:

```
    <tr>
      <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_email; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
        <?php if ($error_email) { ?>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $error_email; ?></span>
        <?php } ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_telephone; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="telephone" value="<?php echo $telephone; ?>" />
        <?php if ($error_telephone) { ?>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $error_telephone; ?></span>
        <?php } ?></td>
    </tr>
```

but in Firefox still the order of attributes is changed (**but not the attribute values!**):

```
<input type="text" value="" name="email" />
```

Same in Chrome - no attribute values are changed. The only reason may be the JavaScript library and/or another theme being used.

Though the doctype of HTML of OpenCart's default theme *is defined* as HTML5, OpenCart actually does not use any HTML5 feature.

Anyway, if there is something making the real use of HTML5 in Your template then do not be afraid and enjoy these features. For example in the very example from Your question, if the input has type `email` or `tel`, then user cannot submit the form until the `email` field contains semantically correct email address and he is even not able to fill in any literal (non-numeric) characters into the `tel` field... (Yep, until the user modifies the HTML via developer tools...)

Comment: I know these features (new input types ) do some validation but in my case they break the form and throw invalid email and tel nr even if they are totally valid and correct. And I was not talking about that form that one is ok. My problem is at the checkout register form. To reproduce this put sth in your basket then go to checkout then choose register. The fields that appear there are called by a js so you can not access that page with js disabled. Thank you for struggleing but I think you misunderstood me

Comment: GitaarLAB I will check soon, sorry I was away all day. Thanks

Comment: @geryjuhasz You can still access that form by calling `http://your.ocinstall.com/index.php?route=checkout/register` (mind the difference). It cannot mark invalid email if the email is valid (i.e. if it marks that email invalid, it is really invalid - post here pls that email address - just change words/letters but keep all unusual characters and dots where they are). I cannot figure out how the form could be broken just by changing the input types, but OK, I accept I may misunderstood You. Merry Christmas!

Comment: it is my email address, the gmail one. it is letters@gmail.com, it is absolutely valid

Comment: Merry xmas!! @geryjuhasz: but .. *are* you using a non-default theme (if so which one)? *Did* you find errors in your browsers/php error-log? Did you post us the full html generated by php (`index.php?route=checkout/register`)? (I already asked all of that in the comments..) Don't leave us here stabbing in the dark

Comment: True it is accessible from that url. Merry Xmas all :)

Comment: the theme is default, output can be found here: [register page](http://returnoffer.net/index.php?route=checkout/register) Please leave a feedback here when you viewed the link, because I have to modify it back, because users are not able to register now, I'll have to change the attribute order back

Comment: @geryjuhasz: I viewed the link and got the full response (html) from http://web-sniffer.net and pasted it here in a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/bCXab6Kb  Under 'Detalii personale' the `name=email` field has type `email`. And both the `name="telephone"` and `name="fax"` are type `tel`. So, javascript (nor the browser) is not the problem and we must look at the php source (and you state it is the default theme). Can you copy the full php-source you are seeing in a pastebin and share it here? I'll have a look at that source once more (assuming you are using the latest version of opencart).

Comment: That`s true. They are of type text in the code, but are parsed as email and tel types.

Comment: Essentially, this answer is right: there are currently no html5 input-fields in opencart, thus there must be something none-default added/installed. Yet I was interested in the what/how/why part of the question and posted that as an answer including an explanation and solution for the failing email-validation.